# how to merge image into center of the video thumbnail?

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I created one media player, it's working fine for me. The media player display number of video thumbnails. I need one play button in center of the videothumbnails so, I added one image(play button). It's display videothumbnails right side corner, i wish to create center...i don't know how to change....please help me.....

my working source code:-

```
private Bitmap getImage(int id) {

Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),id,   
MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
System.out.println("ff"+MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails
.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null));
        Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.play1);
        // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        // canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 10, 10, null);
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumb.getWidth(), thumb
                .getHeight(), thumb.getConfig());
        // Canvas cs = new Canvas(bmp2);
        Canvas canvas= new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.scale((float) 1.0, (float) 1.0);
        //canvas.scale((float) 1.0,(float) 1.0,(float) 0.1,(float) 0.1);
        //canvas.skew((float)0.5,(float)0.5);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0f, 0f, null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(thumb, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.save();
        return bmOverlay;
       }
```

Comment: give me your suggestion, if i ask anything wrong please mention it...i am waiting for your suggestion.....

Comment: friends I got the answer.......cool

Comment: Balaji.. please share your code how you managed to get it to center. Thanks for the above code it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this.

while drawing second bitmap we can use

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 30, 30, null);
```

inseted of

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
```

This 30,30 is Width and Height. you can put whatever you like.